# Preventing onclick-function to be active when in settimeout function

Tags: javascript

Im creating a memory and I almost have it all done. My remaining problem is that while in the setTimeout function,

```
setTimeout(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++){
        if(clearedPairs[i] != i){
            var reset = document.getElementById(cardPosition[i]);
            reset.removeAttribute("style");
        }
    }
    score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML,10) - 10;
    resetValues();
}, 800);
```

If a click occurs on another card, while its waiting to turn the two open cards back over, the player will receive additional minus point, and thats not whats supposed to happen. Can anyone help?

I can post more of the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to watch your state: when in the setTimeout function, set it to `true`. When it's finished and clicks are acceptable, set it to `false`. Then just use an `if` statement in your click handlers to check the state.

```
var inFunction = false;

setTimeout(function(){
    inFunction = true;
    for(i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++){
        if(clearedPairs[i] != i){
            var reset = document.getElementById(cardPosition[i]);
            reset.removeAttribute("style");
        }
    }
    score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML,10) - 10;
    resetValues();
    inFunction = false;
}, 800);
```

Does that address your issue?

Comment: I was just trying to breakout timeout function to a separate and instead doing setTimeout("flippBack()", 800); But I tried you suggested, however it still adds multiple minus score if you click more than the two opening cards :(

Comment: @Cammy Do you want the event to be ignored only when this function is running, or when you have setTimeout running at all? My answer handles the former. If the latter, you'll have to set the state elsewhere.

Comment: Hm well I want it to be ignored while the function is running INSIDE the setTimeout, so I guess both? or maybe I'm understanding the setTimeout wrong. I just realized that mayhaps it just pauses and then after (in this case) 800 msec runs the function thats inside. Though I'm not entirely sure if that matters.. sigh

Comment: From the docs: `Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.` Note that your code execution doesn't pause during the delay.

Comment: Here, let me show you my code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bcqee/) i have an issue with the if on line 106 which seems to be part of the problem. Also my if statement on row 92 has something to do with it.

Comment: @Cammy Change `setTimeout("flippBack()", 800);` to `setTimeout("flippBack", 800);`

Comment: I still need the parentheses to call the function, however I was trying to make my value true with two == .. Newbies you know, thanks for your time anyways :)

Comment: Should've removed double-quotes as well.